# How to achieve to and fro questions like command using commander.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-tool, node-commander

I want to achieve something like folloing using commander.js

```
$ my-tool create-environment
Press ^C at any time to quit.
environment name: (UAT) : Prod
environment url : hhtps:www.google.com

Created new environment Prod
$
```

Please note here user has to hit ENTER after provide environment name and url. Its kind of to and from asking for inout rather than giving all options in single command.

I had been struggling with the commander.js documentation but no luck so far. I would be thankful if someone could help me achieve this.
[Commander documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)

Thanks in advance,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Commander is used for parsing arguments, but does not interactively prompt for missing command-arguments or options.

You could use Commander to process the command-line arguments, then use something like Inquirer to prompt for values which are missing. Using that combination might look like:

```
$ my-tool create-environment --url https://www.google.com
Press ^C at any time to quit.
environment name: (UAT) : Prod

Created new environment Prod

$ my-tool create-environment --name Prod
Press ^C at any time to quit.
environment url : https://www.google.com

Created new environment Prod
```